# Deploying changes to JavaScript files generated from Typescript in IntelliJ; js not updated

Tags: javascript, typescript, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am having a problem with IntelliJ and the automatic deployment of changes while the server is running (in this case Spring Boot).

I have enabled the "Build project automatically" in the IntelliJ options.

When I make a change to a .ts file, the .js and .js.map files in the code are correctly updated.

The .ts file, however, it not updated in the target directory. That is NO problem. I just press the "Compile" shortcut and the .ts file in the target output are updated. Great.

What is NOT updated though are the target .js and js.map files. No matter how many times I open these files and press "Compile" the files in the target are not updated. So the .ts and .js files are now out-of-sync, and I need to restart the server for the .js file change to be noticed.

The weirder part is that all this works just fine on my work computer, with what I can tell the exact same settings. But I cannot get it to work on my home computer.
Neither can a co-worker of mine get it to work on his work computer, and I've looked and looked for any differences in settings.

It is as if IntelliJ watches the files for changes on some setups, and on some setups, they are completely ignored because they were generated.

Can anyone help me with any pointers?

Comment: is the issue reproducible with `tsc -p . --watch` ? You would need to disable inllij watch mode of course.

Comment: (with typescript installed globally or `npx tsc -p . --watch` with a recent node version)

Comment: @JulesRandolph I might be dumb, but I really don't understand what half of that means. Neither where I am supposed to input such arguments, or what they mean. But I appreciate the response :)

Comment: @JulesRandolph Ah, it's a command you give npm. Thing is though, that node generates the files properly, but it's IntelliJ that then doesn't propagate the files into the target output directory.

Comment: `tsc` is the command line interface for typescript, and is shipped with npm typescript package :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured out a solution to this.

By changing the `tsconfig.json` into stating `compilerOptions/outDir` so that it outputs straight into the `target/classes/static` directory, the changes are propagated correctly.
(for me the value became the beautiful `../../../../../target/classes/static/scripts`)

A side effect though is that the source map paths become quite wonky and start showing up as a folder called something alike `C:/.../src/main/resorces/static/...` in the browser dev tools, inside to the JavaScript root directory, and the typescript files had difficulty showing up sometimes, just being blank.

A workaround that I found for this was to also set `compilerOptions/inlineSources` to true and to set `compilerOptions/sourceRoot` to something fictitious like `http://TypeScriptFiles` so it shows up in the browser dev tools as a new root node called `TypeScriptFiles` instead of the weird nested directory.